# Type: Screen bug. Did you now how to fix this error

Tags: import, error

When i installed blender i started to try to import one model but i depared whit this error. [image]

Comment: Looks like a video card issue, are your drivers all up to date and is your card supported by Blender?

Comment: yes they are but this happen i think is conflict in some archivers but i will see this